# android: drawing disappear after gmail

Tags: android, share, resume

I am working on a drawing app where a user can share the picture in the drawing plate, and using the following code:

```
share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(attachment));
share.setType("image/png");
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Drawing"));
```

While the image can be successfully sent through whatsapp or gmail, etc, after finishing gmail action and returning back to the app, the drawing plate's drawing has disappeared.

Yet for whatsapp, the drawing would still be kept after sharing.

Does anybody know why and how could the drawing still remains in the drawView after gmail returns(after going to other app and resume)? Many thanks!

Comment: Have you logged the lifecycle of your Activity? My best guess is that your activity is destroyed and recreated when going to gmail, but that is not the case when going to whatsapp.

Comment: actually i am not that familiar with lifecycle of activity...if then how could that be checked and what is the way to tackle it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html reference to the developer doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will log your major lifecycle callbacks of your Activity, and then you can examine them in your logcat. You will probably have to save some information about your image in your onSaveInstanceState callback, and then restore it in your onCreate callback, assuming that your activity is indeed being destroyed and recreated, but that does seem to be the case.

```
    public class MyActivity exetends Activity {
         private final String TAG = "MyActivity";

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
         }

         @Override  
         protected void onStart() {
             Log.d(TAG, "onStart")
         }

         @Override
         protected void onRestart() {
             Log.d(TAG, "onRestart")
         }

         @Override
         protected void onResume() {
             Log.d(TAG, "onResume")
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPause() {
             Log.d(TAG, "onPause")
         }

         @Override
         protected void onStop() {
             Log.d(TAG, "onStop")
         }

         @Override
         protected void onDestroy() {
             Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy")
         }
         @Override
         protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outBundle) {
             Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState);
         }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! let me investigate and revert asap! really thanks!

Comment: it is because the paths drawn are still there, yet the background bitmap is gone. i have added the following inside OnCreate      if ( savedInstanceState == null )       {
      } 
      else 
      {
????
      }  but dont know how to set back the bitmap.

Comment: Hi permeak, sorry but I don't think I am quite understanding your question.

Comment: Hi Brent Hronik, i have tried your above suggestion and checked with books for the onSaveInstanceState but still fails. Yet I think you have guided to the correct direction. All in all, your answer already fulfills the question and so i have accepted it =) For the new codes, i have asked another question for this as outlined in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116892/android-get-back-bitmap-after-sharing-through-gmail . See if that would be more clear.